# SQLite delete returning more than one record I want to limit to just deleting the the first record found

Tags: java, sqlite, delete-row

I am using SQLite 3.15 and Java 8.

```
String createTableQueryPK = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS fileBlock (id not null,filename not null, PRIMARY KEY(id,filename))";
```

My delete function

```
    public void deleteRecord(String filename) {
    String deleteQuery = "delete from fileBlock where filename=(select * from fileBlock where filename=? order by id limit 1 offset 1)";
            //"delete from fileBlock where filename= (select id, filename from fileBlock where filename=? order by id LIMIT 1);";
    try {
        if(c != null) {
            PreparedStatement prep  = c.prepareStatement(deleteQuery);
            //prep.setInt(1, id);
            prep.setString(1, filename);
            prep.execute();
            System.out.println("record deleted ");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
```

Gets the following error: Error [SQLITE_ERROR] SQL error or missing database (sub-select returns 2 columns - expected 1)
I have tried the following queries any ideas:

```
delete from fileBlock where filename in (select Distinct filename from fileBlock where filename='test9.txt')
```

This deletes all records

The idea of the application is that many files coming from different sources some with the same file name or the same user tring to load the same file

How the application will work submit a file name to the delete function and if it is there take the first record there and remove it.
Yes I know not a good design

The problem is:
How do I delete the first record found in the ressult set and leave all the others intact

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to delete just a single 'random' row that matches the given filename, you'll have to use something unique about that row, such as the `rowid`.

The idea is this (adjust to your database schema as needed):

```
create table t(filename);
insert into t values('One'),('One'),('One'),('One'),
                    ('Two'),('Two'),('Two'),('Two'),
                    ('Three'),('Three'),('Three');
select count(*) from t;  --initially there are 11 rows in this example

delete from t where rowid = (select rowid from t where filename = 'Two' limit 1);

select count(*) from t; -- now, only 10 rows indicating only one row was deleted
```

(Even without the `limit 1` it will work because of the `=` matching only the first value returned, but to be more precise.)

Answer (score 2):

in case you want to delete only one row does not matter  which one.

add limit 1 to delete query 
example:

```
delete from fileBlock where filename=(select filename from fileBlock where filename=? order by id limit 1 offset 1)
limit 1;
```

or 
you can directly execute delete query without select statement if you want.

```
delete from fileBlock where filename=? limit 1;
```

Comment: There is no LIMIT option for the DELETE statement in the default SQLite3. You need to have SQLite3 compiled with the `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT` option to allow `LIMIT`.  So, this is a partly right/wrong answer.

Answer (score 1):

Change this query to return filename instead of `*`

`delete from fileBlock where filename=(select * from fileBlock where filename=? order by id limit 1 offset 1)`

to

`delete from fileBlock where filename=(select filename from fileBlock where filename=? order by id limit 1 offset 1)`

Comment: Thank for the response: the query works but it deletes all the records that have that filename. I just want to delete only one does not matter at this which one

Answer (score 0):

My Solution based off of the below answers

```
    public void deleteRecord(String filename) {
    String deleteQuery = "delete from fileBlock where rowid = (select rowid from fileBlock where filename = ? limit 1);";
    String deleteQuery1 = "delete from fileBlock where filename=(select filename from fileBlock where filename=? order by id limit 1 offset 1)limit 1;";
            //"delete from fileBlock where filename= (select id, filename from fileBlock where filename=? order by id LIMIT 1);";
    try {
        if(c != null) {
            PreparedStatement prep  = c.prepareStatement(deleteQuery1);
            //prep.setInt(1, id);
            prep.setString(1, filename);
            prep.execute();
            System.out.println("record deleted ");
        }
    } catch(Exception e) {
        System.out.println("Error " + e.getMessage());
    }
}
```

The queries above both work
Thank You